# supervisor, gunicorn and django only work when logged in

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm using [this guide](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)  to setting up an intranet server. Everything goes ok, the server works and I can checked it is working in my network.

But when I logout, I get 404 error.

The sock file is in the path indicated in `gunicorn_start`.

```
(cmi2014)javier@sgc:~/workspace/cmi/cmi$ ls -l run/
total 0
srwxrwxrwx 1 javier javier 0 mar 10 17:31 cmi.sock
```

Actually I can se the workers when listed the process list.

```
(cmi2014)javier@sgc:~/workspace/cmi/cmi$ ps aux | grep cmi
javier   17354  0.0  0.2  14652  8124 ?        S    17:27   0:00 gunicorn: master [cmi]
javier   17365  0.0  0.3  18112 10236 ?        S    17:27   0:00 gunicorn: worker [cmi] 
javier   17366  0.0  0.3  18120 10240 ?        S    17:27   0:00 gunicorn: worker [cmi]  
javier   17367  0.0  0.5  36592 17496 ?        S    17:27   0:00 gunicorn: worker [cmi]  
javier   17787  0.0  0.0   4408   828 pts/0    S+   17:55   0:00 grep --color=auto cmi
```

And supervisorctl responds that the process is running:

```
(cmi2014)javier@sgc:~/workspace/cmi/cmi$ sudo supervisorctl status cmi
[sudo] password for javier: 
cmi                              RUNNING    pid 17354, uptime 0:29:21
```

There is an error in nginx logs,

```
(cmi2014)javier@sgc:~/workspace/cmi/cmi$ tail logs/nginx-error.log
2014/03/10 17:38:57 [error] 17299#0: *19 connect() to 
unix:/home/javier/workspace/cmi/cmi/run/cmi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while
connecting to upstream, client: 10.69.0.174, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://unix:/home/javier/workspace/cmi/cmi/run/cmi.sock:/", host: 
"10.69.0.68:2014"
```

Again, the error appears only when I logout or close session, but everything works fine when run or reload supervisor and stay connected.

By the way, ngnix, supervisor and gunicorn run on my uid.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit Supervisor conf

```
[program:cmi]
command = /home/javier/entornos/cmi2014/bin/cmi_start
user = javier
stdout_logfile = /home/javier/workspace/cmi/cmi/logs/cmi_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

#### Gnunicor start script

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="cmi" # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/javier/workspace/cmi/cmi # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/javier/workspace/cmi/cmi/run/cmi.sock # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=javier # the user to run as
GROUP=javier # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3 # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=cmi.settings # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=cmi.wsgi # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/javier/entornos/cmi2014/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

export CMI_SECRET_KEY='***'
export CMI_DATABASE_HOST='***'
export CMI_DATABASE_NAME='***'
export CMI_DATABASE_USER='***'
export CMI_DATABASE_PASS='***'
export CMI_DATABASE_PORT='3306'

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /home/javier/entornos/cmi2014/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application --name $NAME --workers $NUM_WORKERS --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Comment: How are you running supervisor?

Comment: Yes. It seems the cmi (gunicorn) running... And It works when I'm in a session.

Comment: Can you attach your supervisor conf please?

Comment: This is my supervisor.conf

Comment: I'm confused. Why is gunicorn being run from an bash script and not by supervisor?  I would suggest your issue is that the gunicorn instance is not being monitored by supervisor and only the parent script